# Bootstrap: error class not working with hide class

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a form where on error two input fields slide done and i want them to have bootstrap error class. 'error' class works fine without 'hide' class is there, but with 'hide' its being neglected.

HTML:

```
 <div class="control-group hide login">
   <label class="control-label" style="color:red">Username</label>
   <div class="control-group error">
      <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" class="input-large" name="username">
      </div>
   </div>

   <label class="control-label" style="color:red">Password</label>
   <div class="control-group error">
     <div class="controls">
      <input type="password" class="input-large" name="password">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

jQuery:

```
  $(".login").hide();
  $(".login").slideToggle("slow");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by replacing my html code as follows:

```
     <div class="control-group hide login">

        <div class="control-group warning">
          <label class="control-label" for="inputWarning">Username</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="inputWarning" name="username">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group warning">
          <label class="control-label" for="inputWarning">Password</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input type="password" id="inputWarning" name="password">
            <span class="help-inline"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Even though it worked and solved my problem, i still cannot understand how? Any explanation welcomed!